# Localization SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, swiftui, localizable.strings

I want to ask about localization in SwiftUI for my app but something doesnt work. 
I maked everything as in the example but for some reason nothing works:
https://benoitpasquier.com/localization-swiftui-how-top-preview-localized-content/

This code doesnt work:

```
.environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "en"))
```

without any code just adding Localizable (English) I translate the text in the app into English. And when I try to translate for apps in, say, English and Spanish, I have it automatically translated to English(so the default language was chosen by the system). How do I fix this so that the text is translated using the code at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LocalizedStringKey`:

In your app:

```
let greeting: LocalizedStringKey = "Greeting"
let text = Text(greeting)
```

In your English `Localizable.strings` file:

```
"Greeting" = "Hello";
```

In your Spanish `Localizable.strings` file:

```
"Greeting" = "Hola";
```